# Noise in circuit

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

I'm trying to make simple AC motor speed controller. Motor comes from washing mashine with tachometer. I decided to use TL071CP opamp for reading tacho.

And here comes my problem, when I use my lab power supply, and there is no load on the circuit (except Arduino) tacho readings are fine. But as soon as there is some load, or I use some cheap power supply, opamp readings become totally random.
My guess is that problem lays in voltage stabiliser, but I don’t know how to fix it, and i don’t have oscilloscope to see whats going on in circuit. Any idea what can cause that and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: That TACHO comparator circuit is suspect. We don't know Tacho's electrical characteristics, and in general, using an op amp as comparator  is not recommended...its output doesn't drive to digital GND reliably. You're also depending on R7 to protect Arduino's I/O from over-voltage...not a good plan.

Comment: @glen_geek So using proper comparator, like LM393 should fix the problem? My main concern is that i didnt put enough capacitors or they have wrong capacity. The only additional load will be relay module connected to 5V pin (*6), about 200 mA.

Comment: Where are your decoupling capacitors? What does your layout look like? Also, please buy an oscilloscope. Even the cheap USB ones will do the job.

Comment: Not related to your problem but a general tip: draw all your schematics with inputs to the left and outputs to the right with signal flow from left to right. Positive voltages point up, ground and negative point down.

Comment: @winny The only decoupling capacitors are connected to voltage regulators (U2, U3). Should i add some more? Also, thanks for the tips!

Comment: @winny And here is my PCB layout: https://i.imgur.com/wK6sRjR.png

Comment: Please in-line your image. You need decoupling capacitor(s) on every IC and probably every subcircuit.

Answer (score 1):

None of the wires of your tacho are connected to GND. That's a perfect noise magnet. Insert at least a 10...50uF capacitor in parallel with R8.

More: change your tacho amp to a Schmitt-trigger for more noise immunity. Impossible here to give a schematic because the output spec of the tacho is not shown.